# How to access a method (value) that is nested in a public static class

Tags: javafx

How do I access/get the string return values of a public static method that is nested in a public static class?
I want to display the string on a screen.

I've tried using private StringProperty variables to setDataString() the method return values as seen in the code snippet below.

The method named "byteToHex(buffer)" is the one whose return value I'm trying to access.

```
public static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener
{
      final public static char COMMA = ',';
      final public static String COMMA_STR = ",";
      final public static char ESCAPE_CHAR = '\\';

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0)
        {
            try {
                    byte buffer[] = serialPort.readBytes();

                    byteToHex(buffer);

                    TransCeiveSerialData dataString = new TransCeiveSerialData();
                    dataString.setDataString(byteToHex(buffer));    
        /*
         * wait some milliseconds before sending next data package to avoid data losses
         */     
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }catch(InterruptedException ie) 
                    {
                        Logger.getLogger(TransCeiveSerialData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ie);
                    }
            }
            catch(SerialPortException spe) {System.out.println("Error in port listener: "  + spe);}
        }           
    }
}


    public static String byteToHex(byte x[])
    {
        StringBuffer retString = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
        {
            retString.append(Integer.toHexString(0x0100 + (x[i] & 0x00FF)).substring(1));
        }
        return retString.toString();
    }
```

Using for exmaple *`System.out.println("Received data: " + instanceOfClass.getDataString());`*  in an external class to get the method's return string I get a "null". But I expect to get 31323334353637380d0a.

I've also tried binding the values but without any success.

Do you perhaps have any ideas how I can solve this problem? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

AvJoe

Comment: According to parenthesis, isn't this static method outside the class?

Comment: The public static String method is, as you've correctly mentioned, outside the public static class. But they're both part of another class. The code is merely a snippet to keep things a bit orderly.

Comment: I'm not sure what the public static method has to do with your problem (other than you calling it twice unnecessarily). The problem appears to be you setting the property of an instance that only exists inside the scope of the `serialEvent` method. If you want to update a different instance, one that already exists elsewhere, then you need a reference to it. How you get that reference is up to you and depends on the structure of your application.

Comment: The public static method works fine. My problem is how I can access its return values from an external class